# About $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus

Could you show
$$\frac{\pi ^3}{12}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{i \log \left(1+\frac{i}{n x}\right)}{n^2}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}$$

Comment: are you sure that your sum converges?

Comment: The sum should converge absolutely, since $|\tan^{-1}(x)|$ is bounded and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}<\infty,$ but I don't believe this equality. If we write $1+i/nx=r_{n}e^{i\theta_{n}},$ then we should have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}i\log(r_{n})/n^{2}+C$, $C\in\mathbb{R}$ on the left hand side, but the right hand side is clearly real.

Comment: I do not see how this can be true. If $x>1$, the RHS is real and the LHS is not.

Comment: this account expire in two hour , i am tired to many inapropiate and offensive response ,here there are a lot of people want to help but the most it is only interesting in make poins t i do not why , other time some body have to appropiate of many formulas and others do not help really . or because they do not know or think they know more than others and when they do not know they insult or they close the questions who have believed that they are .bye anywa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the expression you propose is wrong:

To know the answer, first you must know some results:

the propose (1) is the relationships among the reciprocal arguments

$$\tan ^{-1}(n x)\tag{1}+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\quad\ ; nx>0$$

the propose (2) is the representation in logarithmic forms:

$$\arctan(nx)=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{1+inx}{1-inx}\right)=\frac{\ln(1+inx)-\ln(1-inx)}{2i}\quad ; nx\in\mathbb{R}\tag{2}$$

this expression is easily obtained using (3) and then integrating it.

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac {1} {2} \left(\frac{1}{1 - i x} + \frac{1}{1+ i x} \right) \tag{3} $$

the propose (4) is the basel problem:

$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.\tag{4}$$

Then taking the (1) expression and applying the summation operator on both sides of the equality obtain, and dividing it by n to square.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left (\tan ^{-1}(n x) + \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)\right)}{n^2}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^2}$$

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}{n^2}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^2}\tag{5}$$

knowing that the right expression converges to the constant, it follows that both series in the left also converge, hence.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(\frac{\pi}{2})}{n^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}{n^2}$$

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}{n^2}$$

for (4).

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^3}{12}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{nx}\right)}{n^2}$$

and the right expression for (2).

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^3}{12}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{i}{nx}}{1-\frac{i}{nx}}\right)\right)}{n^2}$$
Hence the answer is:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\tan ^{-1}(n x)}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^3}{12} + \frac{1}{2i}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\ln\left(\frac{nx-i}{nx+i}\right)}{n^2}$$

$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
 Q.E.D$$